# configuring AWS RDS instance with node.js Application

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services

```
    connection      :   mysql.createConnection({
        host        :         'stock.c9ir51vvjv7s.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com',
        user        :         'user',
        password    :         'password',
        port        :         '3306',
        database    :         'db'
    })
```

I have created a mysql connection with AWS RDS instance. When I'm running my nodejs application locally its going through smoothly, but on deplying it on AWS with the same connection object I'm getting this error

```
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
```

I'm not sure why it's taking localhost

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the value of socket path to the config object:

```
socketPath: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
```

In MAMP, you go to http://localhost:8888/MAMP, and you find:

> /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock

At the end you have:

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : config.host,
  user     : config.user,
  password : config.pass,
  database : config.db,
  socketPath: '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock'
});
```

or
 host: 'localhost'

to

host     : 'cloud_instance_private_ip'